# Python Cookies and PHP virtual()

Tags: php, python, cgi

I narrowed down the problem:

```
os.environ.get('HTTP_COOKIE')
```

This always seems to be None when calling the Python file with that line using PHP's virtual(). Does anyone know why this is?

I'm using Python 2.7 because of how much I need the Python Imaging Library.

**EDIT:** Never mind, it's been fixed. It was because I'm an idiot and didn't know I had to set the cookie's path to /, causing it only to work where the cookie was generated.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set cookies by your own with [apache_setenv](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.apache-setenv.php) function.
But if the only thing that you need from python is PIL, then you probably don't need python at all. PHP have very powerful tools like [MagickWand](http://www.magickwand.org/), a frontend to image magick.

Comment: Actually, I use Python for a lot of things, it's just that I need 2.7 rather than 3.x for PIL. The cookies are (supposed to be) generated by Python, as are most of the pages. But because os.environ.get is always None when I include the Python file, I'm having trouble actually setting/getting the cookies.